# Pandas: Updating dataframe values for rows where one colum has missing data

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframe called **firstpart**.

I'm trying to update the values in one column (**Key**), but only for rows in which another column (**Zone**) has no data.

I'm using this code, which doesn't work:

> firstpart.ix[firstpart.Zone ==np.nan,"Key"] = "newvalue"

Neither does this:

> firstpart.ix[firstpart.Zone =="","Key"] = "newvalue"

Using this syntax I'm able to update values in rows for which Zone has another value, but for some reason not if I try to select the rows in which it is blank.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
firstpart.ix[firstpart.Zone.isnull()] = "newvalue"
```

You can't equate NaN to anything.

```
In [1]: NaN == NaN
Out[1]: False
```

You need special methods for that, and this is what .isnull() is about.